# Asp.net checkbox and html data attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

In asp.net, if you use a custom attribute, usually it is rendered as-is.

Considering this markup (**note:** attributes such as `id`, `name` and `for` were removed in all examples as their generated id/names are verbose):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" data-foo="bar" />
```

Is rendered in asp.net as:

```
<input type="text" data-foo="bar" />
```

That is, asp.net keeps `data-foo` untouched.

Check box are usually rendered like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Normal" />
```

Renders as:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Normal</label>
```

But if you add a custom attribute on a checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Custom attribute" data-foo="bar"  />
```

It renders as:

```
<span data-foo="bar">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Custom attribute</label>
</span>
```

As you can see, a span in rendered to hold the attribute. This also happens if you add the attribute in code behind. This does not happen with any other HtmlControl, AFAIK.

Does anyone know why this span is rendered to hold the attribute?

Is there anyway to render the attribute in the input tag?

Comment: Interesting.. Just curious, what are you using the extra attribute for?\

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's rendered with a span, but I suppose you can add the attribute directly to the `input` element of the `CheckBox` **in code-behid** like this:

```
myCheckBox.InputAttributes.Add(...)
```

Reference links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/p/541142/541562.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add.aspx

**Update**

An additional parent element is used, so that the attributes you apply to a `CheckBox` can affect both the `input` and the text. I suppose it's a `span` (and not a `div`), because it's an **inline element**, making it more convenient to use in different scenarios.

Reference links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Differences_and_default_behavior
- http://learnwebdesignonline.com/span-div

Comment: Nice, I've never noted this InputAttributes before. I tried Attributes.Add, which didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way that render engine builds the `CheckBox` control, there isn't very much to do about it.

Something you could do is creating a `runat="server"` input.

```
<input id="myInput" runat="server" type="checkbox" data-foo="bar"/>
<label>Custom attribute</label>
```

Another option is adding the `data-foo` attribute using jquery on document load

```
$(function(){
    $('span[data-foo]').each(function(){
        var $span = $(this);
        var value = $span.data('foo');
        $span.find('input').data('foo',value);        
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another method that I use when all else fails, you can always use a literal control and make it render whatever you want. You need to do a bit more work when handling the postback, but sometimes this is the only way to get the html you need.

Markup:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myLiteral" runat="server"/>
```

Codebeside:

```
myLiteral.Text = string.Format("<input type=\"checkbox\" data-foo=\"{0}\" /><label>Normal</label>", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access that attribute on click event you can do that by casting the control. For example I have a check box and I assign it a custom attribute like you did

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" data-foo="bar" />
```

Now on `OnCheckedChanged` I need to get that value and in my method I got a `sender` object.

```
protected void chk1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox myControl = (CheckBox)sender;
    string value = myControl.Attributes["data-foo"].ToString();

}
```

I hope this help someone