# Using a C# asp.net dropdownlist instead of HTML ul list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, leaflet

I am using the html list to help find specific areas on a map using leaflet.   This is a normal html ul list but with an  tag insert in between each line.  I have also included the data-position and zoom attributes to pin-point a specific location on the map.

HTML list:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-zoom="6" data-position="57.3666,   -25.0008"> Orginal map.....</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="54.3666,-9.0"> Irish Continental Shelf</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="53.27,-9.91"> Irish Exclusive Economic Zone</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="51.74404,-10.12931"> Irish Territorial Sea</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="53.35547,-6.17153"> Irish Contiguous Zone</a></li>
</ul>
```

ASP DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="BurlyWood">  
    <asp:ListItem  Value="Navigation ToolBox Control">Irish Continental Shelf</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem Value="Standard ToolBox Control">Irish Exclusive Economic Zone</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem Value="Data ToolBox Control"> Irish Territorial Sea</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem Value="Login ToolBox Control">Irish Contiguous Zone</asp:ListItem>  
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now i want to use a asp:Dropdown list but c# sharp dose not allow any  tags. This means I can not link to a specific point on the map using data-postion or zoom.

Is there a way in C# to incorporate this feature?

Comment: What is "with an tag insert in between each line" supposed to mean.....? What tags.....?

Comment: apologies i mean anchor tags for hyperlinks

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
ListItem a1 = new ListItem("Irish Continental Shelf");
        a1.Attributes["data-position"] ="12,54";
        a1.Attributes["test2"] = "2";
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(a1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're really interested in the Attributes of the listitems. In that case, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706714/asp-net-checkbox-and-html-data-attribute) QnA you should use the `InputAttributes` property.

```
myDropDownList.InputAttributes.Add(...)
myListItem.InputAttributes.Add(...)
```

Comment: Did you try this first? `InputAttributes`seems to be a CheckBox-only property.

Comment: Unfortunantly no, don't have a compiler or a project handy at the moment. Seems that the property is normally named `Attributes` on ASP.NET controls.

Comment: Well, I did try it, and neither the DropDownList nor ListItem class has `InputAttributes`. `Attributes` only refers to the attributes to the control itself, inside the opening tag, like `id="foo"` or `style="foo"`. So `Attributes` isn't correct either. And since ListItem doesn't seem to have the `Controls` property either, I'm not sure what would work (there *should* be a way, though....).

Comment: `ListItems` does have a `Attributes` as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx). So by giving the listitems identities it would be possible to manipulate the attributes for them as well.